# Use Python on Qt Creator in Ubuntu Environment

Tags: python, ubuntu, qt-creator

I just install Qt Creator on Ubuntu for python GUI coding.

Can you please guide me that what steps should I follow to start python coding on QT Creator in Ubuntu environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Qt Creator allows you to create Python files (not projects) and run them. It also has syntax highlighting, but it lacks more complex features such as autocomplete.

Running scripts requires some configuration (I used this tutorial). Open Qt Creator and go to Tools->Options->Environment->External Tools. Click Add->Add category and create a new category (for example, Python). Then, select the created category and click Add->Add Tool to create a new tool - RunPy for example. Select the created tool and fill the fields on the right:

1. Description - any value
2. Executable - path to python.exe
3. Arguments - %{CurrentDocument:FilePath}
4. Working directory - %{CurrentDocument:Path}

[image]

Comment: how do I add Executable file in ubuntu

Comment: It's the same as @Fahdkalis wrote but easier since QtCreator also considers the PATH variable thus writing "python" (without the quotation marks) in the Executable-field will be sufficient to run it.